# Process Svn C#, commit does not show/do anything

Tags: c#, svn

I have Process method for SVN, it simply calls commands inside some methods.
For example it shows results if i call it like this `status [path to a file]` or `info [path to a file]`, but does not do anything when i try to commit it `commit -m 'mycommit' [path to a file]`. Although direct commands to command promt is fine. Why is it happens?

```
 private string RunSvn(string svnArgs)
        {
            Process process;

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            psi.FileName = "C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/svn.exe";

            psi.Arguments = svnArgs;

            psi.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

            process = Process.Start(psi);

            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();

            process.WaitForExit();

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: Was something printed to standard error instead perhaps? Also, what was the exit code of the svn process?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ExitCode 1, that all.. :(, i tried to find if it possible to show the error instead of just exit code, and nothing found.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen for example if you make mistake on purpose in command line, it will show some text about it for example Svn help, but process shows only ExitCode 1.

Comment: So did you check standard error instead of standard output? `process.StandardError` that is.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thanks for the advice, now it shows the actual error